# Augmented Reality iOS: marker detection and 3D projection

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, augmented-reality

I need to develop an iOS app, which can detect marker via iPhone camera and project 3D model on top of this marker.

I was looking all day long for some useful information on this topic, but all I got was brainwashing mix of ARToolkit/OpenCV/NyARToolkit/cpp so on and so on... Being a noob when it comes to compiling and combining libraries I downloaded few sample apps from different sources to see if I can understand, but it was only 'black ready to use' magic.
Many of the questions on this topic here on SO are from year or two ago, so maybe there is something valuable.

Using iPhone camera or using OpenGL - there a lot of tutorials to start, but detecting markers/iamges and usage of libraries needed for that is something which is making helpless.
With what and where to start?

Comment: What type of project is this? Some libraries like [QCAR/Vuforia](https://ar.qualcomm.at/) openly send analytics to Qualcomm servers. That may be fine for a personal project, but users of your commercial app might not agree.

Comment: let say I'd like to make it something like this: http://augmentedev.com/

Comment: the look and feel of the app and marker resembles QCAR's implementation. As long as you warn users (say via the first time run agreement) that analytics are being collected, why not be open to it?

Answer (score 2):

I found this https://github.com/jonmarimba/NyArToolkit-iOS

I didn't tried this, beacause I am using [NyARToolKit for Unity3d](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wp/?page_id=556), Its Great.

NyARToolKit for Unity3D comes with samples.Its very easy to create apps(iOS,Android,desktop) using Unity3D.

Check this [tutorial](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/07/01/augmented-reality-on-the-iphone-using-nyartoolkit-w-code/)

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

try [metaio](http://dev.metaio.com/en/) sdk [for iphone](http://dev.metaio.com/en/sdk/getting-started/),supports everything you need..

Comment: Metio sdk is not available now

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with new Vuforia iOS SDK. They released version #2 in December - it's quite cool, with cloud recognition and previous stuff too. Though it's really hard to bite through it does its job I think.

Comment: they have quite nice support and many people post their code snippets how to achieve something, so do not hesitate and try ;)

Comment: Hey thats really a great SDK.Can you please help me how to create our own Image Markers for this ?

Comment: @AjaySharma Have you found any solution to create your own marker and scan that?

Comment: I'm not working on it for few months now, but afaik you can use Cloud Recognition to create multiple markers and then scan them. Though you have to read on their site for details, something might have changed since I've dealt with it